# Create factory for public_activity rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am using the public_activity gem and I have a method which deletes an activity record when its trackable parent is deleted. As per below.

```
def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.destroy
      @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_type: "Comment", trackable_id: @comment.id).first
        @activity.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end
  end
```

I have tried quite a few different names to use for the public_activity factory however none seem to work and return `trait not registered`

How can i set up a public_activity factory with the correct name?

factories.rb

```
factory :activity do
   trackable_id :answer
   recipient_id :user
   owner_id :user
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blind answer, try this:

```
factory :activity, class: 'PublicActivity::Activity' do
   trackable_id :answer
   recipient_id :user
   owner_id :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for FactoryBot:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :activity, class: 'PublicActivity::Activity' do
    association :trackable, factory: :answer
    association :recipient, factory: :user
    association :owner, factory: :user
  end
end
```